# How to code a new class within a win form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is the a way in a win form app code in a new class with namespace and constructor??

Comment: Can you give us a use case for what you mean? What you're asking isn't clear.

Comment: What do you mean "within" the Winform (app)? Should it be a nested class? If not, the most straight forward way would be to just place the new class in a separate source file.

Comment: @gwpcoder: Can you explain *in a win form app code in a new class*, a bit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can write a new class in the same file, or in its own file, in a new namespace or the same namespace.

[some basic c# syntax](http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=16)

Comment: The website you linked to is a bit very hard to read and probably intimidating to newbies, but... I can’t think of any better to answer *such* a question either :)

Comment: I feel a bit fraudulent getting upvotes for such a throwaway answer TBH!